# Django JS TypeError: data.data is undefined

Tags: javascript

Why oh Why? I'm trying to create and object with the contents of all of the checkbox status and ids from the HTML page I have.
Why is my data undefined?

```
 function attachskillls(){

    var data = {}

    $(".checkbox").each(function(){
        var obj = {}
        obj[this.id] = $(this).prop('checked')
        data['data'].push(obj)
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/skill/attch/",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
}
```

Comment: Check your console for sure you will be getting error at this `data['data'].push(obj)` line.

Comment: Yes but  I knew that, I wanted to know what is wrong with it

Comment: `data['data']` you not yet initialized it as an array so how can you perform push operation on that. so you need to do something like `if(data.hasOwnProperty('data')){
data.data.push(obj);
} else {
data['data'] = [];
data.data.push(obj);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared data as an object

```
    var data = {}
```

Now, you are iterating through checkboxes and executing this

```
  data['data'].push(obj)
```

data['data'] is not an array so data['data'].push will fail.

To achieve this, you could do something like this

```
 var data = {};
 data['data'] = []
```

This ensures that the data['data'] is an empty array. Then follows the rest of the code.

Hope you understand the issue now.

Comment: Gleaming, Thanks very much

Comment: just got to work out why no data is being put in now and its all good haha